# Get summary of tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Model.summary() gives me a this output
[image: model summary]

Now how can i check sequential_1 layers and sequential_3 layer?
I want whole model summary but it gives two sequential so that means two model are combined so how can i get summary of both model?
I only have [model.h5](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YLJ-jBpU1_Qc0tXO-L3vuWredaEuGPG3) file nothing else

Answer (score 1):

**Models saved in .h5 format includes everything about the model.**

To inspect the layers summary inside the Model in a Model, like in your case.
You could extract the layers, then call the summary method from each of them.

ie.
`layer_summary = [layer.summary() for layer in loaded_model.layers]`

Here is the complete code I used in reproducing your scenario.

```
import tensorflow as tf
print('Running Tensorflow version {}'.format(tf.__version__)) # Tensorflow 2.1.0

model_path = '/content/keras_model.h5'

loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path)
loaded_model.summary()

inp = loaded_model.input   
layer_summary = [layer.summary() for layer in loaded_model.layers]
```

I've also used the **model.h5** file you uploaded.

Comment: It works, but ends up with "AttributeError: 'InputLayer' object has no attribute 'summary'"